# Derive number of number pyramid from index number

Tags: java, math, loops

The problem goes like this:

Suppose I have a number `N`, whose value is used to create a number pyramid. A number pyramid for `N`= 4 would look like this:

```
      3
    2 3
  1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

Equivalently, it could look like this:

```
      0
    1 1
  2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

Needless to say, I want to know of a way to traverse through every number of the pyramid by using an index. I am seeking a function akin to:

`f(i) = [number from pyramid]`

where `i` is the index number. It would be best if it were only dependent on index (i.e. not recursive).

I've tried to look for a pattern in an indexed list like

`N=4`
`([0 0] [1 1] [2 1] [3 2] [4 2] [5 2] [6 3] [7 3] [8 3] [9 3])`

The first number in each pair is the index, where the second is the number from the pyramid.

Alas, I've had no luck in finding a clear pattern.

Comment: What does this question have to do with CUDA?

Comment: I'm using this function as an algorithm for a cuda kernel. Basically, the index here would be the index of each kernel call. If you feel that this question is too general for cuda, feel free to edit the tags.

Comment: all I can see a costly way :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elaboration on Egor's answer:

The first occurrence of `X` is at

```
sum(0<=i<=X | i) = X(X+1)/2
```

Now assume you have some index `i`, then we first solve as if the function was not discrete and round down in the end:

```
X(X+1)/2 = i      <=>
X^2 + X - 2i = 0
```

Solve this quadratic equation:

```
X = (-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 8i)) / 2
```

Simplifying, ignoring the negative solution and rounding down yields the formula given by Egor:

```
f(i) = floor((sqrt(8i+1)-1)/2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I can understand the process much more clearly now.

Answer (score 3):

```
f(i) = floor((sqrt(8*i+1)-1)/2)
```

Comment: Could you show how you derived this function? And is `8` specific somehow to the value of `N`?

Comment: Ah magic numbers, reminds me of the US version of The Office and kevin's use of magic numbers to balance the accounts.

Comment: @Zchpyvr - It doesn't depend on `N`.  It is a solution of quadratic equation based on your pattern.